# marionette ItemView ui returning array?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am using the Mariontte ItemView 'ui' to create short hands for selectors.

```
  class MyView extends App.Views.ItemView

    ui:
      myItem:       "#item"
```

[image]

However when I call @ui.myItem I'm being returned an array so the actual element is inside @ui.myItem[0]
What's causing this behavior? It's an issue for me as I'm doing a compare between @ui.myItem with the event.target element from an event so they don't match and now I have to do some fiddling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery thing. When it selects an element it's actually storing it in an array-like object. Using `@ui.myItem[0]` to compare is one way to go. Another way is `@ui.myItem.get(0)`.

While the first approach above is what I would recommend, you could also compare using [jQuery.is](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Comment: that works thanks! still weird that it's an array if I provide an ID and not a class

Comment: I know what you mean but it's actually an array-like object, as you can see in your inspector, providing access to the selected items by index but also including other data that jQuery uses to do what it does.